# Find GCD pairs for given array

Tags: java, algorithm

Given an array of integers of size n, where n is an even number. Pick 2 numbers from the array and find the GCD. Similarly, pick 2 items from the remaining items in the array and find the GCD. Repeat the steps to find the GCD pairs. Sum the GCD values and get the highest sum.

**constraints:**

```
n is in range 2 to 20
arr[i] is in range 1 to 10^9
```

**Example 1:**

```
arr = [3,4,9,5]
```

**Answer:**

```
4
```

**Explanation:**

```
a) gcd of (4,5) is 1
b) gcd of (3,9) is 3
Sum = 1+3 = 4. This is the highest possible GCD sum.
```

**Example 2:**

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

**Answer:**

```
6
```

**Explanation:**

```
a) gcd of (1,5) is 1
b) gcd of (2,4) is 2
c) gcd of (3,6) is 3
Sum = 1+2+3 = 6. This is the highest possible GCD sum.
```

This is my code:

```
public static int solve(int[] ar) {
   int n = ar.length;
   Arrays.sort(ar);
   int sum = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) {
     int a = ar.get(i), b = ar.get(n-i-1);
     int c = gcd(a,b); 
     sum += c;
   }
   return sum;
}

static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    // if b=0, a is the GCD
    if (b == 0)
        return a;

    // call the gcd() method recursively by
    // replacing a with b and b with
    // modulus(a,b) as long as b != 0
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

My code is working for 1st example and gives the wrong output for the second example.
I have debugged and found that the approach I am using is not correct. What is the correct approach to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't know about correct, but with `n<=20` even extreme brute force is feasible. Backtrack through all the possible pairings?

Comment: Or sligthly less bruteforcy and probably still correct - find the pair with the highest gcd, remove, repeat.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question, but for coding style, I recommend always using curly braces even if it's only one line: `if(shouldDoStuff){ doStuff }`. It makes intention unambiguous. Omitting them _will_ come back to bite you eventually.

Comment: @teapot418 Counterexample to the greedy algorithm: `[3, 4, 15, 20]`. Greedy chooses gcd(15,20) then gcd(3,4) for a total of 6. But the correct answer is gcd(3,15) and gcd(4,20) for a total of 7.

Comment: I'd go with a bottom up dynamic programming approach. The subproblems can be represented by a 20-bit number where a 0 bit means a number that hasn't been used yet, and a 1 bit means the number has been used. There are half a million subproblems to solve.

Comment: @user3386109, can you show the pseudo-code for the dynamic programming approach?

Comment: @teapot418, I tried the approach `find the pair with the highest gcd, remove, repeat` it worked for only few inputs and fails for case mentioned by  
user3386109

Comment: @user3386109 that *information* is not enough - there is more than one possibility (3?) to create two pairs given 4 numbers

Comment: @user3386109, I question whether dynamic programming can be used here, based on my understanding of the problem. If you believe it can you need to flesh out the details, preferably in an answer. DP depends on the "principal of optimality" being satisfied. In a nutshell, it means once you arrive in a certain state S, the optimal solution when traversing from S to an end state does not depend on how you reached S; hence, the concept of state variables. What do you see as the state variables?

Comment: @CarySwoveland DP depends on identifying common subproblems, and solving each subproblem exactly once. For example, consider an input array with 20 elements. If we begin by pairing element 1 with 2, and element 3 with 4, then that leaves the subproblem of finding the best pairings for the remaining 16 elements. OTOH, if we start with pairs [1,3],[2,4], or [1,4],[2,3], then we'll get a different partial sum for the first four elements, and we're left with the exact same subproblem (finding the best sum for the remaining 16 elements).

Comment: @user3386109, doesn't that amount to smart enumeration, by using information obtained when solving for `[1,3],[2,4]` when dealing with `[1,4],[2,3]`, but what does that have to do with dynamic programming? Again, I encourge you to put up a DP solution. If it works it would be great.

Comment: From [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), dynamic programming *"refers to simplifying a complicated problem by breaking it down into simpler sub-problems"*. And yes, you could call that smart enumeration if you want.

Answer (score 1):

We can recursively search all possible ways to compute total GCD. How?

If the array contains just two elements, we can just return GCD of it's two elements.

If it contains more, let's iterate over all the pairs of values. For each pair, we compute it's GCD, and we also call our function recursively with a copy of the array with the two values removed. If we add the result of both computations together, we get a total GCD for our currently selected pair of values.

Now we just keep track of the best GCD we found so far, and return it at the end.

Here is code that (should) do exactly that.

```java
int solve(int[] ar) {
  // If we have only two elements, there's not much else we can do.
  if(ar.length == 2) {
    return gcd(ar[0], ar[1]);
  }

  //Keep track of the largest GCD
  int best = 0;
  
  // for every pair of values in the array
  //  make a copy of the array without the pair and call recursively
  for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
      
      int score = gcd(ar[i], ar[j]);
      
      // Make a copy
      int[] ar2 = new int[ar.length - 2];
      int copy_k = 0;
      for(int k=0; k < ar.length; k++) {
        // Skip values that we already visited
        if(k == i || k == j) {
          continue;
        }
        
        ar2[copy_k] = ar[k];
        copy_k += 1;
      }
      
      // Call recursively
      score += solve(ar2);
      
      if(score > best) // We found a better pair
        best = score;
    }
  }
  
  return best;
}
```

This algorithm is quite slow. If you need to speed it up, there are at least two areas of possible improvement:

- Computing GCD is an expensive operation. *Pre-computing GCD for all possible unique pairs of values and storing them in a hashmap would eliminate double-computing.*
- It checks some possible permutations multiple times. (e.g. selecting first pair and then second pair in the next recursion is the same as selecting second pair and then first) *I have some vague idea on how to solve that, but it's too late in the night today, sorry.*

**It is very likely that faster algorithm exists, this is just from the top of my head.**

**Edit**: Well, after some sleep, it dawned on me. If we omit the outer loop when creating pairs, we won't get any duplicate ordering of pairs. Basically just replacing `i` with 0 everywhere, like so:

```java
for(int j = 1; j < ar.length; j++) {
    
  int score = gcd(ar[0], ar[j]);
  
  // Make a copy
  int[] ar2 = new int[ar.length - 2];
  int copy_k = 0;
  for(int k=1; k < ar.length; k++) {
    // Skip values that we already visited
    if(k == j) {
      continue;
    }
    
    ar2[copy_k] = ar[k];
    copy_k += 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: The can be thought of as a "greedy" heuristic algorithm. The problem is that you have no way of measuring the quality of the solutions it produces; i.e., by how much the value your solution might deviate from the optimal value. That problem is shared, of course, with most heuristics for optimization problems. The exceptions are heuristics for certain problems that provide upper bounds on the difference between the values for solutions generated and the (unknown) optimal value. I don't see how such bounds might be calculated for this problem.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland I'd be happily proved wrong, however my code should visit every possible **set** of pairs of numbers and select the one with highest value. Can you provide reasoning or ideally counterexample that proves my code wrong?

Comment: My code (should) be correct by induction, even if awfully inefficient. Two-element array is obviously correct, for four-element array we take all the (eight) possible pairs, for each compute GDC of both the pair and remaining array, then choose the best score.

Comment: @KryštofVosyka Your code is correct. As you stated, it tries every possible set of pairs. The code in edit is brilliant! It still tries every possible set of pairs, but does so much more efficiently than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING: There is no free lunch!**

**The problem**

I understand that, given an array containing an even number of positive integers, the problem can viewed as first partitioning the array into two equal-size arrays, then establishing a 1-1 mapping between those two arrays, after which the GCDs of all mapped pairs are computed and summed. The objective is to find a partition and subsequent 1-1 mapping that yields the smallest sum of GDCs.

**Illustrative array**

Suppose the given array is as follows.

```
arr = [317, 29, 355, 388, 214, 375, 186, 301, 374, 323]
```

**Prime factorization**

Most languages provide a method or function to compute each positive integer's *prime factorization*. For example, the prime factorization of `388` can be found to equal `(2^2)*(97^1)`, where `2` and `97` are primes. This can be represented by the array `[[2,2], [97,1]]` where each element is comprised of a prime and its exponent.

If we compute the prime factorization for each element of `arr` we may construct a hash (a.k.a hash table, dictionary) such as the following.

```
PF = {
  317=>[[317, 1]],
   29=>[[29, 1]],
  355=>[[5, 1], [71, 1]],
  388=>[[2, 2], [97, 1]],
  214=>[[2, 1], [107, 1]],
  375=>[[3, 1], [5, 3]],
  186=>[[2, 1], [3, 1], [31, 1]],
  301=>[[7, 1], [43, 1]],
  374=>[[2, 1], [11, 1], [17, 1]],
  323=>[[17, 1], [19, 1]]
}
```

This allows us to quickly retrieve the prime factorization for any element of  `arr`:

```
PF[388]
  #=>[[2, 2], [97, 1]]
```

**Computing GCDs from prime factorizations**

Next, for any two positive integers, say `108` and `360`, consider how their GCD is computed, given their prime factorizations.

```
PF = { 108=>[[2, 2], [3, 3]], 360=>[[2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1]] }
```

If we view this as

```
PF = { 108=>[[2, 2], [3, 3], [5, 0]], 360=>[[2, 3], [3, 2], [5, 1]] }
```

we see that the GDC equals

2<sup>min{2,3}</sup> * 3<sup>min{3,2}</sup> * 5<sup>min{0,1}</sup> = 2<sup>2</sup> * 3<sup>2</sup> * 5<sup>0</sup> = 4 * 9 * 1 = 36

We may now construct a hash that maps each pair of elements of `arr` into their GDC:

```
GDC = {
  [317,29]=><gdc>, [317,355]=><gdc>,...,[317,323]=><gdc>,
  [29,355]=><gdc>,  [29,355]=><gdc>,..., [29,323]=><gdc>,
  ...
  [374,323]=><gdc> 
}
```

Note that since `GDC[[x,y]] == GDC[[y,x]]` we need only compute one-half of the pairs.

**Partition the given array into equal-size partitions**

Suppose we partition `arr` into two equal-size arrays. For example,

```
a1 = [375, 355, 186, 323, 29]
a2 = [317, 388, 214, 301, 374]
```

**Solve an assignment problem for each partition**

For this partition we wish to find the 1-1 mapping between `a1` and `a2` that minimizes the sum of the (here `5`) GCD's. This is called an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), a type of *linear program* (LP).

This can be formulated as an LP with (here 25) variables x<sub>i,j</sub>, each of which equals `1` if element `a1[i]` is *assigned* to element `a2[j]` and equals `0` otherwise. The model also has (here `5`) constraints that ensure each element of `a1` is assigned to exactly one element of `a2` and (here `5`) constraints that ensure each element `a2` is assigned to exactly one element of `a1`.

Though LP variables are not restricted to taking on integer values, it is known that the optimal value of each assignment problem variable will equal `0` or `1`.

Every assignment problem is characterized by a matrix of *distances*. Here that matrix is `5x5`, each `i,j` element being taken from the GDC hash corresponding to a pair `[a1[i], a2[j])`. The value of a given assignment is the sum of the distances associated with the assignment. The optimal solution is an assignment whose value is minimum over all possible assignments.

Assignment problems can be solved relatively quickly using either the Simplex Method, a specialized algorithm for the assignment problem alone or another general-purpose LP algorithm.

**Enumerate partitions of the given array to find an optimum**

We now have a way to way to obtain the optimal assignment for each partition of `arr` into two equal-size arrays. If `arr` contains `n` elements there are `n!/((((n/2)!)^2)` such partitions. For the example (for which `n = 10`) that is `252` partitions.

It therefore remains to enumerate all such partitions and select one (possibly the only one) for which the optimal value of that associated assignment problem is minimal. For the example we are dealing with we wish to obtain "all combinations of 10 elements taken 5 at a time":

```
[
  [317, 29, 355, 388, 214],
  [317, 29, 355, 388, 375],
  ...
  [214, 186, 301, 374, 323],
  [375, 186, 301, 374, 323]
]
```

These are the `a1` arrays. Each corresponding `a2` array equals `arr - a1(i)`:

```
[
  [[317, 29, 355, 388, 214], [375, 186, 301, 374, 323]],
  [[317, 29, 355, 388, 375], [214, 186, 301, 374, 323]],
  ...
  [[214, 186, 301, 374, 323], [317, 29, 355, 388, 375]],
  [[375, 186, 301, 374, 323], [317, 29, 355, 388, 214]]
]
```

Comment: "*Most languages provide a method or function to compute each positive integer's* prime factorization." -> so Java - the question is marked with that tag - is not one of "Most languages" :-(  at least I do not know that method in the standard library

Comment: @user85421, then I guess for Java one would have to [roll their own](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-efficiently-print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/), which would not be difficult.

Answer (score -3):

Calculate the *greatest common factor* of all pairs, and *sum* the values.

Here is an example.

```java
int solve(int[] ar) {
    Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
    for (int a : ar)
        for (int b : ar) {
            if (a == b) continue;
            s.add(gcd(a, b));
        }
    return s.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).sum();
}
```

Alternately, use a *stream*.

```java
int solve(int[] ar) {
    return Arrays.stream(ar)
                 .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(ar)
                                     .map(y -> x == y ? 0 : gcd(x, y)))
                 .distinct()
                 .sum();
}
```

Comment: OP didn't specify that elements may not repeat in the array. The code currently fails for array [5,5] (should return 5, but your code returns 0)

Comment: @KryštofVosyka, you should write an answer!

Comment: @Reilas You beat me to it.

Comment: @KryštofVosyka, I thought it was incorrect?

Comment: Yes, it still is incorrect. But I've written an answer :-)